# How can I get a unique identifier for a datastore entry clientside using ndb?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm am moving to using ndb now that it's out of the experimental phase. There are a few things that I need to rethink and one thing I am having trouble with is grabbing a unique identifier for a model entity client side. I grab entities as follows and send them to client side

```
questions = Questions.query()
self.values_for_client()["questions"] = questions
```

Then client side I iterate through each entry and then I set up a link for further investigating the model entry.

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href = "/view_details/{{question.key}}">View</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I used to get a unique identifier like **asdfer234234===** but now I get something like **Key('Questions',%203)** from {{question.key}}. I would then capture this unique identifier and use it like

```
question_key = Key(str(cgi.escape(key)))
question = Questions.all().filter("__key__ =", question_key).get()
```

How can I replicate this behaviour with ndb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want question.key.urlsafe()

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_urlsafe

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the quick response. As a follow up the actual implementation that worked was {{question.key.urlsafe}} i.e. no following ()

Comment: ah, yeh, that's the template system taking care of that for you.

Comment: also, fyi, to turn that id back into a real key you can use ndb.Key(urlsafe=id) in your code..

Comment: Finally, have a look at the db/ndb conversion guide, where you could have found this information: https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/edit (a.k.a. NDB Cheat Sheet)